# I ran smartctl and I am glad it says that it passed the overall health test, but I am worried about the 120 reallocated sector count

Tags: hard-drive, smart

```
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5" HDD MQ01ABF...
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MQ01ABF050
Serial Number:    563TT0VST
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 701e00efc
Firmware Version: AM0P2D
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Dec  1 20:52:46 2020 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 120) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 128
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   099   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       593
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       120
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   060   060   000    Old_age   Always       -       16114
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3715
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1252
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       262
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   084   084   000    Old_age   Always       -       160450
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       32 (Min/Max 11/51)
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0032   062   062   000    Old_age   Always       -       15578
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       34624675632
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       27836621543
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 46937 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 46937 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 16104 hours (671 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 00 08 58 2e 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x002e5808 = 3037192

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 00 08 58 2e 40 00      01:55:31.055  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 18 f0 f2 61 6a 40 00      01:55:31.055  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 20 e8 4a 62 6a 40 00      01:55:31.055  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 e0 7a cb 2a 40 00      01:55:31.055  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 d8 ea bd 1a 40 00      01:55:31.055  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 46936 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 16104 hours (671 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 50 08 58 2e 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x002e5808 = 3037192

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 b8 7a cb 2a 40 00      01:55:26.911  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 20 b0 4a 62 6a 40 00      01:55:26.906  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 18 a8 f2 61 6a 40 00      01:55:26.906  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 50 08 58 2e 40 00      01:55:26.890  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 28 2a 66 11 40 00      01:55:26.889  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 46935 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 16104 hours (671 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 b0 08 58 2e 40  Error: WP at LBA = 0x002e5808 = 3037192

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 08 10 f2 0b 51 40 00      01:55:22.635  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 f0 ea 09 50 40 00      01:55:22.635  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 e8 92 09 50 40 00      01:55:22.634  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 08 32 09 50 40 00      01:55:22.633  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 00 6a 08 50 40 00      01:55:22.633  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 46934 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 16104 hours (671 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 a8 08 58 2e 40  Error: WP at LBA = 0x002e5808 = 3037192

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 08 d8 f2 07 10 40 00      01:55:22.178  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 a8 08 58 2e 40 00      01:55:18.477  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 28 d0 0a 66 11 40 00      01:55:18.459  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 38 00 58 2e 40 00      01:55:18.444  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 98 28 e2 03 aa 40 00      01:55:18.444  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 46933 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 16104 hours (671 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 a0 08 58 2e 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x002e5808 = 3037192

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 80 a0 00 58 2e 40 00      01:55:14.288  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 80 98 80 57 2e 40 00      01:55:14.287  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 80 90 00 57 2e 40 00      01:55:14.286  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 80 88 80 56 2e 40 00      01:55:14.286  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 80 80 00 56 2e 40 00      01:55:14.285  READ FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16114         -
# 2  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%     16088         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed: read failure       00%     16056         11470
# 4  Short offline       Completed: read failure       00%     16055         11470
# 5  Short offline       Completed: read failure       00%     16055         11470
# 6  Short offline       Completed: read failure       00%     16055         11470
# 7  Short offline       Completed: read failure       00%     16055         11470
# 8  Short offline       Completed: read failure       00%     16054         11470
# 9  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%     16054         -
#10  Short offline       Completed: read failure       00%     16052         11470
#11  Short offline       Completed: read failure       00%     16052         11470
#12  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%     16046         -
#13  Short offline       Completed: read failure       00%     15343         368296
#14  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     14996         -
#15  Short offline       Aborted by host               50%     14996         -
#16  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     13750         -
#17  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3162         -
#18  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3161         -
#19  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      80%      3161         -
#20  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3161         -
#21  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3161         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**NCQ**

You have NCQ disk errors.

```
  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 00 08 58 2e 40 00      01:55:31.055  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 18 f0 f2 61 6a 40 00      01:55:31.055  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 20 e8 4a 62 6a 40 00      01:55:31.055  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 e0 7a cb 2a 40 00      01:55:31.055  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 d8 ea bd 1a 40 00      01:55:31.055  READ FPDMA QUEUED
```

Native Command Queuing (NCQ) is an extension of the Serial ATA protocol allowing hard disk drives to internally optimize the order in which received read and write commands are executed.

Edit `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` and change the following line to include this extra parameter. Then do `sudo update-grub` to write the changes to disk. Reboot. Monitor hangs, and watch `/var/log/syslog` or `dmesg` for continued error messages.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.force=noncq"
```

**bad block**

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

<strike>`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test</strike>

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program to do
         a read-only scan of the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block
         inode to prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice, then the bad block scan
         will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks found by
         running badblocks(8) will be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively. This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```

Comment: what does reboot monitor hangs mean

Comment: is it also okay if i wait until tomorrow to do this

Comment: You can ignore the "Monitor hangs" part. Do it whenever you can. Report back.

Comment: aite get back to u tmrw

Comment: im going to sleep rn, but do you know how i can access initramfs? would be very helpful

Comment: You shouldn't need/want to get to initramfs. Why do you ask?

Comment: well, I dont have a live usb/disc rn, I might be able to get one tomorrow but until then id need to use initramfs instead of a live usb

Comment: @Killah4Ever  At the initramfs prompt, type `fsck -f /dev/sdaX`, replacing the X with your Ubuntu partition number. Are you not able to boot at all right now?

Comment: ik what to do when i get to the initramfs prompt, i'm asking how can i get to it, i can boot and it works very well, i already did the update grub thing, no errors so far. I'm just wondering how I can access initramfs

Comment: @Killah4Ever You don't get to the initramfs prompt unless there's an error. Did you do the items in my answer?

Comment: yes, the only thing i haven't done yet is e2fsck with live usb because i don't have it rn, i'll probably make one tomorrow

Comment: oh yeah before doing that, i just wanna ask, on the disks app it says i have 120 bad sectors, is that something to worry about?

Comment: @Killah4Ever Not a problem unless the bad block scan fails, or updates that number by a lot.

Comment: @heynnema - you say, do not badblock scan, do not interrupt. How to understand the last comment 'unless bad block scan fails...' ? Thank you

Comment: @jaromrax You don't BBS a SSD. You don't interrupt a BBS unless you want incomplete/inaccurate results. If you have a spinning disk, a BBS failure usually indicates a bad/unrecoverable HDD.